# why /proc/[PID]/exe can be broken?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm looking around /proc and I'm wondering why **/proc/[PID]/exe** can be broken.

I mean , /proc is a pseudo-filesystem and the principle behind it is

> **/proc** provides infos about running processes and kernel data structures

and many other file in that folder has a similar one (principle).

So , the principle behind /proc/[PID]/exe should be

> **/proc/[PID]/exe** provides executable's absolute path

but ***broken links*** break this rule; so , what's the true principle behind this "symlink" ? What's the practical usage "behind the scenes" , that is in kernel internals ?

Or maybe this is a nigthmare of mine , and /proc is just "for users" , meaning that kernel doesn't really use these infos (and so they can be *imperfect*) ?

Comment: Why do you think every executable **has** to have an inode linked to a non-deleted dentry that really exists at all? If that were true you could never upgrade a running program without shutting it down first (or renaming to a temporary filename that you then have to clean up later).

Comment: Anyhow -- can you extract a question here that falls within [the topic guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? Right now I'm not sure it's specific enough to be answerable without going into a bunch of really foundational background first; if you narrowed it to make it clear that you actually *understand* the underlying background (ie. what an inode is; the existence of lazily-unmounted filesystems; etc) and still have a question, that would be helpful.

Comment: A broken symlink still points to a specific path, just one that doesn't exist at the moment.  No rule about the definition of `/proc` is being broken here.

Comment: Yes /proc is "for users", it  reflects the internal structures in the kernel, though those structures exists whether or not the filesystem is mounted. If you start a program and then remove that executable, the symlink cannot point to an existing filename(since you just removed it), which is why you can see a broken symlink - and that's not a problem for anyone.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're right, my question doesn't follow guidelines , i'll try to improve it in preciseness

Comment: @nos i suspected it ; btw , to be precise,  removing bins isn't the only way for breaking symlink : processes running in docker containers, whose bins are only on containers and not on docker host, have that symlink broken on docker host (but this is another question ...)

Comment: @Lil'Jepp, right -- that's because you have a different filesystem namespace with a different mount table. You can switch the current one to move *into* a place where it's valid, but that doesn't mean it's valid from anywhere/everywhere -- if it had to be, we'd be back in a place where you'd be forcing the kernel to disallow things that would otherwise be reasonable and allowable.